# Change Workflow

Tags: workflow

I have workflows set up for items within a list.  1st workflow is manually kicked off.  2nd workflow is to run when an item is changed.  What is happening is if the item is input, without setting off the 1st approval workflow, but the user goes back into the item and makes a change, the 2nd workflow is being kicked off.

Is there a way to not kick off the change workflow until the 1st workflow has been thru the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have it work with those two separate workflows I would say switch the first one so it runs on item creation rather than manual.  If you do that it will always run before the second workflow when it is on change.

If that doesn't work for you then I would suggest putting both workflows together into one and running it on change.  Then use conditionals in your workflow to determine what sections to run at what time.

Answer (score 0):

Put a field in your list to contain completion status of your first workflow say "ApprovalComplete". Set this field to "Completed" from your first workflow when your first workflow completes. Use the "Wait For" activity in the second workflow that starts automatically.

Something like

```
if CurrentItem:ApprovalComplete not equals Completed
    Wait For CurrentItem:ApprovalComplete to equal Completed
```

This will hold your second workflow until your fist workflow completes.

Hope this helps.